# Extension Method ConvertAll

Tags: c#, extension-methods

What is the proper use of ConverAll ? Will it convert one type to another type?

like

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
intList.Add(10);
intList.Add(20);
intList.Add(30);
intList.Add(33);

var query= intList.ConvertAll(x=>(double)x);
```

for this i can use cast or OfType<>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) isn't an extension method, it's a real method on `List<T>` itself.

It returns a new list containing the converted elements. So in your example, the `query` variable isn't actually a query, it's a `List<double>`.

[`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) *are* extension methods that operate on `IEnumerable` and return an `IEnumerable<T>`. However they're not suitable for your stated purpose: `Cast` can convert reference types but *cannot* convert value types, only unbox them. `OfType` doesn't perform any conversion, it just returns any elements that are already of the specified type.

Answer (score 2):

[`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) will just call your delegate/anonymous method for each element of the list. What this does is entirely up to you.

In the example code you posted, it will attempt to cast each element to a double and return that, which means you'll get a `List<Double>` in return.

You should not use `OfType<T>`, since this will filter the elements based on the type, and will only return a different type than the original if it is type compatible due to inheritance or interface implementation.

In other words, `.OfType<Double>` will return no elements, since none of the ints are also doubles.

Answer (score 1):

`ConvertAll` is a projection operator and maps most closely to LINQ's `Select`. LINQ's `Cast` is a specific projection operator and represents doing what you did [via projection] - or it would (as pointed out in Luke's answer [and comment], which I +1'd) if you weren't converting to a value type.

In general, LINQ has a more complete and well-thought-through set of operators, which makes older stuff like `ConvertAll` look a bit silly at times [like this]. (or [@stoopid](http://www.javaposse.com/index.php?post_id=556419) :D).

Comment: The `Cast` method isn't appropriate for what the OP is trying to do. `Cast` *will not work* for value-type conversion (eg, from `int` to `double`). The `Cast` method can only unbox value types, not convert them.

Comment: Miles ahead of you (was editing that in having read your edit - thanks for doing the spadework!) :P (Your answer is great - I only bothered answering before it existed)

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge, `OfType<T>` will only return the elements in the collection that are of the specified type T.
ConvertAll allows you to convert the elements to another type.