# IEnumerable<T>.ConvertAll & DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, ienumerable

I have an interesting need for an extension method on the IEumerable interface - the same thing as List.ConvertAll. This has been covered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913955/extension-method-convertall) and I found one solution [here](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/08/converting-ienumerable-to-ienumerable.html). What I don't like about that solution is he builds a List to hold the converted objects and then returns it. I suspect LINQ wasn't available when he wrote his article, so my implementation is this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOutput> ConvertAll<T, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (null == converter)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("converter");

        return from item in collection
               select converter(item);
    }
}
```

What I like better about this is I convert 'on the fly' without having to load the entire list of whatever TOutput's are. Note that I also changed the type of the delegate - from Converter to Func. The compilation is the same but I think it makes my intent clearer - I don't mean for this to be ONLY type conversion.

Which leads me to my question: In my repository layer I have a lot of queries that return lists of ID's - ID's of entities. I used to have several classes that 'converted' these ID's to entities in various ways. With this extension method I am able to boil all that down to code like this:

```
IEnumerable<Part> GetBlueParts()
{
    IEnumerable<int> keys = GetBluePartKeys();
    return keys.ConvertAll<Part>(PartRepository.Find);
}
```

where the 'converter' is really the repository's Find-by-ID method. In my case, the 'converter' is potentially doing quite a bit. Does anyone see any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue I see with this approach is it's completely unnecessary.

Your `ConvertAll` method is nothing different than [`Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TResult>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), which is a standard LINQ operator.  There's no reason to write an extension method for something that already is in the framework.

You can just do:

```
IEnumerable<Part> GetBlueParts() 
{ 
    IEnumerable<int> keys = GetBluePartKeys(); 
    return keys.Select<int,Part>(PartRepository.Find); 
}
```

Note: your method would require `<int,Part>` as well to compile, unless `PartRepository.Find` only works on int, and only returns Part instances.  If you want to avoid that, you can probably do:

```
IEnumerable<Part> GetBlueParts() 
{ 
    IEnumerable<int> keys = GetBluePartKeys(); 
    return keys.Select(i => PartRepository.Find<Part>(i)); // I'm assuming that fits your "Find" syntax...
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing this out...just leaving my answer for those who are still struggling without LINQ.

Comment: Oh my gawd - Reed you're absolutely right. Shoot - never mind everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Why not utilize the `yield` keyword (and only convert each item as it is needed)?

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOutput> ConvertAll<T, TOutput>
        (this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if(null == converter)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("converter");

        foreach(T item in collection)
            yield return converter(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, using LINQ with Select, which he did previously, streams the results in a very similar manner to this.  Granted, I like your version (slightly) better, but it's basically just doing what the Select() method does internally.  Both your and the original poster's will only convert as needed, and stream results.